# Method worked in Activity but not in a fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-service, android-fragmentactivity

i converted my activity to a fragment, the method network_reinit_activity worked fine before, but when i run it in fragment it wont, this is the method:

```
private final Context c = getActivity();

private void network_reinit_activity() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Activity mainAct = (Activity)c;
            Intent new_i = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationActivity.class);
        mainAct.finish();
        Intent srv_i = new Intent(c, RadioStreamService.class);
        srv_i.putExtra("RS_STREAM_URL", RS_STREAM_URL);
        getActivity().stopService(srv_i);
        if(isInForeground)
    //          startActivity(new_i);
        }
    }).run();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fragment does not finish, the activity finish, please see below code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Activity mainAct = (Activity)c;
            Intent new_i = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationActivity.class);
             getActivity().onBackPressed()   // to finish fragment
             Intent srv_i = new Intent(c, RadioStreamService.class);
             srv_i.putExtra("RS_STREAM_URL", RS_STREAM_URL);
             getActivity().stopService(srv_i);
             if(isInForeground)
             //          startActivity(new_i);
             }
    }).run();
```

Comment: Thank u for ur help ;)